# Modify text of next element from id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

My HTML:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1">
  <label for="check-1">foo</label>
</li>
```

I am trying to change "foo" to "bla" with this JS code:

```
$("#check-1 label").text("bla");
```

but nothing happens and I am getting no errors. I also tried with [:first-child](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
$('label[for=check-1]').text('bla');
```

Answer (score 1):

In input there is not child elements, you can use [`$.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to get next element after input

```js
$("#check-1").next('label').text('bla');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1">
  <label for="check-1">foo</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `label` is not a child of the `input`.  It's the *next* element:

```js
$("#check-1").next().text('bla');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-1">
  <label for="check-1">foo</label>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#check-1 + label").text("bla");
```

Comment: Very good, thank you. If I want to get the `<li>`, I should use `-` or again `+`?

Comment: Do you know of a way to get to `<li>` if I have reached the label?

Comment: you can use $("#check-1).parent()

Comment: IF you want to change the next <li> element label text you can use $("#check-1").parent().next().children("label").text("bla");